# Why do we require disjunct sets here?

Tags: integration, measure-theory

Let $A$ and $B$ be two not necessarily disjunct sets. Why is the following not okay?, $$\int_X 1_A + 1_B \ d \mu = \int_X 1_A \ d \mu + \int_X 1_B \ d \mu = \mu(A) + \mu(B)$$

I'm looking at an exercise solution online which mentions that $\textit{A and B are disjunct, and therefore :}$, followed by above equation. But I don't see why it shouldn't hold anyways?

Comment: You are right. The sets do not have to be disjoint for this. That comes in by $1_{A\cup B}=1_A+1_B$

Comment: Are we also assuming that $A$ and $B$ are measurable sets?

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ and $B$ are not disjunct, than $$\int_{X}\mathbf{1}_{A}+\mathbf{1}_{B}d\mu =1\mu\left(A\setminus B\right)+2\mu\left(A\cap B\right)+1\mu\left(B\setminus A\right)=$$
$$=1\mu\left(A\setminus B\right)+1\mu\left(A\cap B\right)+1\mu\left(A\cap B\right)+1\mu\left(B\setminus A\right)=\ldots$$

Here $A\cap B$, $A\setminus B$ and $B\setminus A$ are disjunct, so thanks to the additivity property of $\mu$
$$1\mu\left(A\setminus B\right)+1\mu\left(A\cap B\right)=\mu\left(A\right)\;\;\;\text{and}\;\;\;1\mu\left(A\cap B\right)+1\mu\left(B\setminus A\right)=\mu\left(B\right),$$
therefore $$\int_{X}\mathbf{1}_{A}+\mathbf{1}_{B}d\mu=\ldots=\mu\left(A\right)+\mu\left(B\right)=\int_{X}\mathbf{1}_{A}d\mu+\int_{X}\mathbf{1}_{B}d\mu.$$
I think you are right.

Comment: By the way the integral is a linear functional, so it must be true...